# Why Google cloud vision auto create many Computer Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-vision

My application run normal until now.
But suddenly one service account (used for google cloud vision) create many Computer Engine instances(about 32 instances).
I checked log and see this line.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBXr1.png)

My billing increase from 10 to 200$/day :(
Anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

This does not seem normal as the Vision API does not require to create Compute Engine instances to work with. It is possible that your credentials might have been filtered. I suggest you [remove the service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#deleting_a_service_account) that is generating the problem and [create a new one](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#creating_a_service_account). Also you can contact Google Cloud billing support if you need more information on your charges. You can fill [this form](https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/cloud_platform_billing) to get in touch with them.